# Что делает, означает аннотация @Stable?

Tags: java, аннотации

вот к примеру в классе String есть такое вот выражение

```
@Stable
private final byte[] value;
```

в комменте написано

```
/**
 * The value is used for character storage.
 *
 * @implNote This field is trusted by the VM, and is a subject to
 * constant folding if String instance is constant. Overwriting this
 * field after construction will cause problems.
 *
 * Additionally, it is marked with {@link Stable} to trust the contents
 * of the array. No other facility in JDK provides this functionality (yet).
 * {@link Stable} is safe here, because value is never null.
 */
```

в первую очередь мне непонятно эта часть

```
/* Additionally, it is marked with {@link Stable} to trust the contents
 * of the array.*/
```

ВАЖНО! Если по каким то причинам решили ставить минусы на мой вопрос, тогда будьте любезны оставить комменты с описанием причины. Иначе не ясно, что не так (формулировка? тема? ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Значение аннотации `@Stable` в `OpenJDK 12`

Открываем джавадоки класса [`jdk.internal.vm.annotation.Stable`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/vm/annotation/Stable.java):

```java
package jdk.internal.vm.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

/**
 * A field may be annotated as stable if all of its component variables
 * changes value at most once.
 * A field's value counts as its component value.
 * If the field is typed as an array, then all the non-null components
 * of the array, of depth up to the rank of the field's array type,
 * also count as component values.
 * By extension, any variable (either array or field) which has annotated
 * as stable is called a stable variable, and its non-null or non-zero
 * value is called a stable value.
 * <p>
 * Since all fields begin with a default value of null for references
 * (resp., zero for primitives), it follows that this annotation indicates
 * that the first non-null (resp., non-zero) value stored in the field
 * will never be changed.
 * <p>
 * If the field is not of an array type, there are no array elements,
 * then the value indicated as stable is simply the value of the field.
 * If the dynamic type of the field value is an array but the static type
 * is not, the components of the array are <em>not</em> regarded as stable.
 * <p>
 * If the field is an array type, then both the field value and
 * all the components of the field value (if the field value is non-null)
 * are indicated to be stable.
 * If the field type is an array type with rank {@code N > 1},
 * then each component of the field value (if the field value is non-null),
 * is regarded as a stable array of rank {@code N-1}.
 * <p>
 * Fields which are declared {@code final} may also be annotated as stable.
 * Since final fields already behave as stable values, such an annotation
 * conveys no additional information regarding change of the field's value, but
 * still conveys information regarding change of additional components values if
 * the type of the field is an array type (as described above).
 * <p>
 * The HotSpot VM relies on this annotation to promote a non-null (resp.,
 * non-zero) component value to a constant, thereby enabling superior
 * optimizations of code depending on such a value (such as constant folding).
 * More specifically, the HotSpot VM will process non-null stable fields (final
 * or otherwise) in a similar manner to static final fields with respect to
 * promoting the field's value to a constant.  Thus, placing aside the
 * differences for null/non-null values and arrays, a final stable field is
 * treated as if it is really final from both the Java language and the HotSpot
 * VM.
 * <p>
 * It is (currently) undefined what happens if a field annotated as stable
 * is given a third value (by explicitly updating a stable field, a component of
 * a stable array, or a final stable field via reflection or other means).
 * Since the HotSpot VM promotes a non-null component value to constant, it may
 * be that the Java memory model would appear to be broken, if such a constant
 * (the second value of the field) is used as the value of the field even after
 * the field value has changed (to a third value).
 *
 * @implNote
 * This annotation only takes effect for fields of classes loaded by the boot
 * loader.  Annotations on fields of classes loaded outside of the boot loader
 * are ignored.
 */
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Stable {
}
```

Поле может быть помечено как стабильное, если все переменные его компоненты изменяют свое значение не более одного раза. Значение поля учитывает значения его компонентов. Если поле типизировано как массив, то все ненулевые его компоненты, включая вложенные компоненты, также учитываются. Кроме того, любая переменная (массив или поле), аннотированная как стабильная, называется стабильной переменной, а ее ненулевое значение называется стабильным значением.

Поскольку значения по умолчанию любого поля есть null для ссылок (соотв., ноль для примитивов), отсюда следует, что эта аннотация указывает на то, что первое ненулевое значение, сохраненное в поле, никогда не будет изменено.

Если поле не относится к типу массива, в нем нет элементов массива, то значение, указанное как стабильное, является просто значением поля. Если динамический тип значения поля является массивом, а статический - нет, то компоненты массива не считаются стабильными. 
*(я так понял, речь идет об **ArrayList** и прочих коллекциях)*

Если поле имеет тип массива, то как значение поля, так и все компоненты значения поля (если значение поля не равно null) считаются стабильными. Если тип поля является типом массива с рангом N > 1, то каждый компонент значения поля (если значение поля не равно null) рассматривается как стабильный массив ранга N-1.
*(я так понял, имеются ввиду двухмерные, трехмерные и т. д. массивы)*

Поля, объявленные как final, также могут быть аннотированы как стабильные. Поскольку final поля уже ведут себя как стабильные значения, такая аннотация не передает никакой дополнительной информации об изменении значения поля, но все же передает информацию об изменении значений дополнительных компонентов, если тип поля является типом массива (как описано выше).

Виртуальная машина HotSpot полагается на эту аннотацию для приравнивания ненулевого значение компонента к константе, тем самым обеспечивая лучшую оптимизацию кода, зависящего от этого значения (например, свертка констант). Конкретнее, виртуальная машина HotSpot будет обрабатывать ненулевые стабильные поля (final или нет) аналогично static final полям, повышая значение поля до константы. Таким образом, оставляя в стороне различия для нулевых/ненулевых значений и массивов, final stable поле рассматривается как если бы оно действительно было final как для языка Java, так и виртуальной машины HotSpot.

В настоящее время не определено, что произойдет, если полю, аннотированному как стабильное, присваивается третье значение (путем явного обновления стабильного поля, компонента стабильного массива или final stable поля с помощью reflection или других средств). Поскольку виртуальная машина HotSpot приравнивает ненулевое значение компонента к константе, может оказаться, что модель памяти Java будет нарушена, если такая константа (второе значение поля) используется в качестве значения поля даже после того, как значение поля изменилось (на третье значение).

**В текущей имплементации**
Эта аннотация действует только для полей классов, загруженных посредством boot loader. Аннотации на полях классов, загруженных вне boot loader, игнорируются.